# trying to count the seconds while my users is with the mouse over an element

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am new in Javascript and I am trying to count the seconds while my users is with the mouse over an element.But I can`t get the interval to stop. Here is my code until now. Thanks

```
 var seconds = 0;
var el = document.getElementById('ceva');

function incrementSeconds() {
seconds += 1;
el.innerText = "You have been here for " + seconds + " seconds.";

}

var x;

document.getElementById("ceva").onmouseenter = function() {var x = 
setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000)};

function mouseLeave() {
clearInterval(x`);
}

 document.getElementById("ceva").onmouseleave = function() {mouseLeave()};
```

Comment: For a start, remove the `var` from `var x = setInterval`. Also fix the syntax `clearInterval(x\`);`

Comment: Thank you . that worked . When I copied the code  here that ' got in there .

Comment: But of course you can`t initialize a variable two times . That got away from me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "var" in the mouseenter function. Change it as below

```
document.getElementById("ceva").onmouseenter = function(){
  x = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000)
};
```

Comment: Thank you .I forgot that there .

Comment: Cool :) . Happy Coding